# select distinct -> join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, pivot, union

Hi i need to mix (more than join) three tables, but the id could be present or not on each table (Please see the example below).

I have spend a few days trying join and union but all time some data is missing!!! can someone give me a fresh idea?

Thanks

[image: data example]

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Comment: Sorry is for mysql

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL had implemented `FULL` joins, this would be fairly simple:

```
select 
    id, 
    a.price as price_1701, 
    b.price as price_1702, 
    c.price as price_1703
from 
    t_1701 as a
    full join t_1702 as b using (id)
    full join t_1703 as c using (id)
order by
    id ;
```

Unfortunately it hasn't (and neither the sister implementation MariaDB), so you have to restore using a `UNION` and `LEFT` joins:

```
select 
    id, 
    a.price as price_1701, 
    b.price as price_1702, 
    c.price as price_1703
from 
    ( select id from t_1701
      union
      select id from t_1702
      union
      select id from t_1703
    ) as t
    left join t_1701 as a using (id)
    left join t_1702 as b using (id)
    left join t_1703 as c using (id)
order by
    id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union to "mix" the tables, and then use an aggregate function such as max to filter out null where there exists a value:

```
select id, max(price_1701), max(price_1702), max(price_1703)
from (
    select id, price as price_1701, null as price_1702, null as price_1703
    from t_1701
    union all
    select id, null as price_1701, price as price_1702, null as price_1703
    from t_1702
    union all
    select id, null as price_1701, null as price_1702, price as price_1703
    from t_1703
) as t
group by id
```